# Program will not run properly outside of Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I am writing a program for school and I have the curious problem of it not running outside of Visual Studio.  Whether release or debug, whether run with debugging or not, it will run when run from Visual Studio.  However, when I run it from Explorer, it will open and spawn the windows I require, but fail when I run the "actual program part".

For context, the program takes data from a number of devices (radiation detectors) and does some basic processing as well as saving the raw data to a text file.  I am using a DLL and some ActiveX controls provided by the hardware vendor, and the program is based upon their sample code.  When the program runs, a simple box with a "Spawn" button appears.  Hitting this will open up identical windows, which can each be used to connect to a different detector.  After making some settings changes, one can hit "start" on each of these to begin a thread that polls the device for data from time to time, etc.  The program crashes when the "start" button is activated.

I am using C++ with MFC.

The only error I can extract from the whole thing is:
0xC0150010: The activation context being deactivated is not active for the current thread of execution.

Are there any ideas?  Is there any other information I can provide that will be useful?

EDIT1:
`int nResponse = dlg.DoModal();`
This is the only bit of code in the stack trace once it breaks that is anything in my code.

I ran Dependency Walker and added a few DLL files to the directory:
mcbcio32.dll
mcbloc32.dll
ieshims.dll

EDIT2:
No more errors with depends.exe.

Here is the "start" code:

```
void CCraneWowDlg::OnStart()
{
    CStatic *pLatest = (CStatic *)GetDlgItem(IDC_LATEST);
    CEdit *pFilePath = (CEdit *)GetDlgItem(IDC_FILEPATH);
    CString strFilePath, strText;
    CFile dataFile;
    LISHDR myHeader;
    LPTSTR errText = "lol";

    try {
        pFilePath->GetWindowText(strFilePath);
        if (!dataFile.Open(strFilePath, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeReadWrite, NULL)){
            AfxThrowOleDispatchException(0xab,(LPCTSTR)"file open not work",0);
        } else {
    //lock the dropbox, set up the device.
            //TODO: lock dropbox
            pLatest->SetWindowText((LPCSTR)m_ConnCtl.Comm((LPCSTR)"STOP"));
            pLatest->SetWindowText((LPCSTR)m_ConnCtl.Comm((LPCSTR)"CLEAR_ALL"));
            pLatest->SetWindowText((LPCSTR)m_ConnCtl.Comm((LPCSTR)"START"));
            UpdateInfo();
    //write the real header
            MakeHeader(&myHeader);
            dataFile.Write(&myHeader,256);
            dataFile.Close();
    //end real header
    //begin getting data
//          AfxBeginThread((AFX_THREADPROC)GetData,(LPVOID)&dataFile,THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,0,0,NULL); //TODO use thread ID to close it if stop is pressed 
//          GetData(&dataFile); //make this a thread with a loop
    //use CThread
            CEdit *pSize = (CEdit *)GetDlgItem(IDC_SIZE);
            CEdit *pEvery = (CEdit *)GetDlgItem(IDC_EVERY);
            CEdit *pMax = (CEdit *)GetDlgItem(IDC_MAX);

            pSize->GetWindowText(strText);
            m_Size = _tstof(strText);
            pEvery->GetWindowText(strText);
            m_Every = _tstof(strText);
            pMax->GetWindowText(strText);
            m_Max = _tstof(strText);
            m_FilePath = strFilePath;

            m_Address = m_DListCtl.GetSelAddress();

OutputDebugString("here we are about to start the thread\n");

            m_DataThread.m_pDlg = this;
            m_DataThread.Start();
            //TODO: thread
//          GetData();
//          dataFile.Close();
        }
    } catch(COleDispatchException *pE) {
        pE->GetErrorMessage(errText, 30, NULL);
        pE->Delete();
        pLatest->SetWindowText(errText);
    }
    UpdateInfo();
//  m_ConnCtl.Comm((LPCSTR)"STOP");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It is not a problem with a DLL.  The exception code is normally caused by a threading problem, like closing the dialog from a thread other than the one that created it.  You commented the code that creates a thread, does it match the actual code you tested?

Comment: This code is what I have now, yes.  I have had some interesting times getting threading to work for this hardware; it's quite possible that is the problem.

Comment: All of the UI is in one thread, the new threads do not interact with the dialogs. (...Or they shouldn't.  I'll check again.)  The threads only poll the hardware via some controls and create some files (that are not opened by the UI thread).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the current working directory is different, so the [DLL search path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586.aspx) is different.  Maybe a different version of the device library is being loaded.

The [Dependency Walker tool](http://dependencywalker.com/) is often helpful in troubleshooting these problems.

Comment: I did this, thank you.  It does not solve my immediate problem, but I did find a few DLL files that were "missing" and put them in the directory.

Comment: @user667840: Did you try "profiling mode", which monitoring DLL loading while the program runs, and also shows you debug output?

Comment: This option is greyed out.  The particular computer I'm on is x64, but I am compiling for x86; is this the cause?

Comment: @user: You must use the version of Dependency Walker that matches your application's bitness, so on 64-bit Windows you generally wind up installing both.

Comment: Haha, silly me.  When I run the x86 version, the errors are gone.  But the program still does not run correctly.

Comment: @Gentry: When running in profiler mode, do you get some debug output in the Dependency Walker window?  Also, have you tried starting the program outside Visual Studio, then using the debugger "Attach to Process" menu option?  That way Visual Studio won't affect the environment of the application, but will still debug any problems that occur.